# Swift - best way to show alert with loading indicator right away after button is clicked?

Tags: ios, swift

I tried using the main thread to show but it didn't work, any thought why the alert doesn't show up right away?

```
@IBAction func updateData(_ sender: Any) {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Updating data", message: "Please wait...", preferredStyle: .alert)
    alert.view.tintColor = UIColor.black
    let loadingIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRect(x: 10,y: 5,width: 50, height: 50)) as UIActivityIndicatorView
    loadingIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
    loadingIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.gray
    loadingIndicator.startAnimating();

    alert.view.addSubview(loadingIndicator)
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.present(alert, animated: true)

    }
```

Comment: currently there's a delay before the alert show up

Comment: Any reason you are dispatching it on the main queue? Instead of directly presenting it.

present(alert, animated: true)

Comment: I was having this problem earlier, it seems to only happen when a viewController is my initial View Controller but if I segue into the controller, it seems to work fine

Comment: I tried directly presented it before without dispatching to the main thread and there was a delay as well. When I stepped through the code, after self.present(alert, animated: true), the alert still doesn't show

Comment: Thanks for all the responses. I had to put the updated code in the completion block of the alert,  self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: {
            do{...

Answer (score 5):

`UIAlertController` can not be customized, so for me the best solution was to create a custom UIView XIB and then instatiate it on the `ViewController` I need.

The XIB View could be like this: 
[image: XIB View]

then you create a CustomAlertLoadingView.swift file which subclass `UIView`, associate it to the XIB and create the `IBOutlets`.

To show it in any `ViewController` just create this extension

```
extension UIViewController {
     func presentAlert(title: String) {
        let nib = UINib(nibName: "CustomAlertLoadingView", bundle: nil)
        let customAlert = nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil).first as! CustomAlertLoadingView

        customAlert.tag = 12345
        customAlert.titleAlertLabel.text = title
        customAlert.indicator.startAnimating()


        let screen = UIScreen.main.bounds
        customAlert.center = CGPoint(x: screen.midX, y: screen.midY)

        self.view.addSubview(customAlert)
    }
}
```

use `self.yourViewController.presentAlert(title:"yourTitle")`

To dismiss the alert, create this function inside the `UIVIewController` extension

```
func dismissCustomAlert() {
        if let view = self.view.viewWithTag(12345) {
            view.removeFromSuperview()
        }
}
```

then call `self.yourViewController.dismissCustomAlert`

Comment: Should i use unique tag for different view controllers?

Comment: @ShadeToD no you shouldn't

Answer (score 2):

I had to put the code needed for execution in the alert completion call back

```
 self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: {
        do{...}
```

})

that solved the delay response

Answer (score 1):

I ran this through Xcode without any delay:

```
@IBAction func updateData(_ sender: UIButton) {
    print("button fire")
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Updating data", message: "Please wait...", preferredStyle: .alert)
    alert.view.tintColor = UIColor.black
    let loadingIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRect(x: 10,y: 5,width: 50, height: 50)) as UIActivityIndicatorView
    loadingIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
    loadingIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.gray
    loadingIndicator.startAnimating();

    alert.view.addSubview(loadingIndicator)
    self.present(alert, animated: true)

}
```

I replaced the `sender` parameter of your function with a `UIButton` and took out the Dispatch call to the main queue since it's unnecessary. No delays at all!

When you say that there is a delay do you mean only when you step trough the code? Because yes if you're stepping through it, the alert view won't be displayed right after `self.present(alert, animated: true)`. You'll have to wait until the function completes execution. But that "delay" isn't visible to the human eye. Did you trying running the above code without stepping through it?

Answer (score 0):

Adjust the Alert view constraints to set the UIActivityIndicatorView.

```
    func presentLoader() {

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)
        let activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(style: .large)
        activityIndicator.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        activityIndicator.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        activityIndicator.color = .blue
        activityIndicator.startAnimating()
                
        alert.view.addSubview(activityIndicator)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            alert.view.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 95),
            alert.view.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 95),
            activityIndicator.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: alert.view.centerXAnchor),
            activityIndicator.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: alert.view.centerYAnchor)
        ])
        
        present(alert, animated: true)
    }
```

Result:

[image]